# Check SQL Server DateAdd for -ve value before update

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

We have the following columns for our time capture table to collect time stamp for each users.

```
Entered
Exited
```

When using the following query

```
select entered, exited as ORIGINALEXIT, DATEDIFF(second, entered, exited), 
DATEADD(ss, -40, exited) AS AFTERCALC, 
DATEDIFF(SECOND,entered, DATEADD(ss, -40, exited)) as AftercalcSeconds
from <table> where deptName = 'Research'
```

The output is as follow:

```
|Entered------------------|Exited-------------------|(NO)|AFTERCALC-----------------|AftercalcSeconds|
|2016-12-14 11:14:15.000 | 2016-12-14 11:14:16.000 | 1  | 2016-12-14 11:13:36.000   | -39            |
|2016-12-14 11:14:30.000 | 2016-12-14 11:14:32.000 | 2  | 2016-12-14 11:13:52.000   | -38            |
|2016-12-14 11:14:05.000 | 2016-12-14 11:14:43.000 | 38 | 2016-12-14 11:14:03.000   | -2             |
```

Expectation:

We need a query which can check if "AfterCalcSeconds" falls in -ve value or not, If it falls in -ve value we need to skip and keep the original value which is in column (NO) else we need to keep the result to the "AfterCalcSeconds"

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: your requirement is not clear,please explain along with examples and show expected output

Comment: Can you get a native English speaker to help you re-write your question?   I have no idea what you are trying to ask.

Comment: How do you expect to get help if that's all you give?  Give some more info.  What's the input?  What's the expected output?  Where do you call `DATEADD` and `DATEDIFF`?  What parameters do you put in those functions?

Comment: I hope the question clarity is ok now.

Comment: if you can include an example of what you want the final result to look like then we can help

Comment: I have resolved the issue. Thank you all the support.

Answer (score 0):

To check if "AftercalcSeconds" column has negative value, I used DateDiff function

```
CASE WHEN
    DATEDIFF(SECOND, entered, exited) < 0 
THEN
    //condition
ELSE
    //else condition
END
```

Thank you for the support!